# Assign Object Data to Geometrie Data in Autocad Map3D or Civil 3D

Tags: autocad

I have lines in my Drawing. All of them has Start Z and End Z geometry-values. In the Object Data every line has variables named Start_z and Ende_Z. I want to copy all Start_Z-Values to the Start Z Geometry-Value and all Ende_Z-Values to the Ende Z Geometry-Values.

How i can do this automatically?

[image]